# Problem with DataTables after updating data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, treegrid

I created a Datatables using the Datatable treeGrid:
https://github.com/homfen/dataTables.treeGrid.js

my code:

```js
$('#exampleButton').on("click", function(){
  let Data = d();
  dt(Data);
});
function dt(data){
var columns = [
{
    title: '',
    target: 0,
    className: 'treegrid-control',
    data: function (item) {
        if (item.children) {
            return '<span>+</span>';
        }
        return '';
    }
},
{
    title: 'Name',
    target: 1,
    data: function (item) {
        return item.name;
    }
},
{
    title: 'Position',
    target: 2,
    data: function (item) {
        return item.position;
    }
},
{
    title: 'Office',
    target: 3,
    data: function (item) {
        return item.office;
    }
},
{
    title: 'Extn.',
    target: 4,
    data: function (item) {
        return item.extn;
    }
},
{
    title: 'Start date',
    target: 5,
    data: function (item) {
        return item.start;
    }
},
{
    title: 'Salary',
    target: 6,
    data: function (item) {
        return item.salary;
    }
}
];
$('#example').DataTable({
    'destroy': true,
    'columns': columns,
    'data': data,
    'treeGrid': {
        'left': 10,
        'expandIcon': '<span>+</span>',
        'collapseIcon': '<span>-</span>'
    }
});
}
function d(){
  return [
        {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421",
            "start": "2011\/04\/25",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Hermione Butler",
                    "position": "Regional Director",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "1016",
                    "start": "2011\/03\/21",
                    "salary": "$356,250"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                                    "position": "Developer",
                                    "office": "San Francisco",
                                    "extn": "8196",
                                    "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                                    "salary": "$86,500"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Shad Decker",
                                    "position": "Regional Director",
                                    "office": "Edinburgh",
                                    "extn": "6373",
                                    "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                                    "salary": "$183,000"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Michael Bruce",
                                    "position": "Javascript Developer",
                                    "office": "Singapore",
                                    "extn": "5384",
                                    "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                                    "salary": "$183,000"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Donna Snider",
                                    "position": "Customer Support",
                                    "office": "New York",
                                    "extn": "4226",
                                    "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                                    "salary": "$112,000"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421",
            "start": "2011\/04\/25",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Hermione Butler",
                    "position": "Regional Director",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "1016",
                    "start": "2011\/03\/21",
                    "salary": "$356,250"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421",
            "start": "2011\/04\/25",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Hermione Butler",
                    "position": "Regional Director",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "1016",
                    "start": "2011\/03\/21",
                    "salary": "$356,250"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421",
            "start": "2011\/04\/25",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lael Greer",
                    "position": "Systems Administrator",
                    "office": "London",
                    "extn": "6733",
                    "start": "2009\/02\/27",
                    "salary": "$103,500",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jonas Alexander",
                            "position": "Developer",
                            "office": "San Francisco",
                            "extn": "8196",
                            "start": "2010\/07\/14",
                            "salary": "$86,500"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shad Decker",
                            "position": "Regional Director",
                            "office": "Edinburgh",
                            "extn": "6373",
                            "start": "2008\/11\/13",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Michael Bruce",
                            "position": "Javascript Developer",
                            "office": "Singapore",
                            "extn": "5384",
                            "start": "2011\/06\/27",
                            "salary": "$183,000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Donna Snider",
                            "position": "Customer Support",
                            "office": "New York",
                            "extn": "4226",
                            "start": "2011\/01\/25",
                            "salary": "$112,000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--datatable-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!--datatable-treegrid-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables-treegrid@1.0.4/dataTables.treeGrid.js" integrity="sha256-klXMhqbeoG/fvl7/eBOnTx62ZDuc/QLbMqSoAP49tcY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    

<table id="example"></table>
<button type="button" id="exampleButton">Clique me!</button>
```

The DataTable is created, but when I call this function again by passing a new 'data' (like when I click the button more than once), the expandIcons (+ and -) stop working.
I get this:

```
error {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables-treegrid@1.0.4/dataTables.treeGrid.js",
  "lineno": 134,
  "colno": 26
}
```

So I can't expand the content anymore.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that DataTable will put your container #example inside of another div #example_wrapper, so when you click again there is not just your clean element.

To solve this, create the #example element dynamically inside of a div container.

```
<div id="div_container" ></div>
```

...then call this before the method to build the table.

```
$('#div_container').html('<table id="example"></table>');
```

Comment: So, won't I have a table in my html code? I will test this. :)